# WordPress Custom Post Logic

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I'm a newbie here, but I've been trying to understand and research this for the past couple of days to no avail.

I created a custom post type (video) with a taxonomy associated with it (industries). The taxonomy "industries" has multiple categories (I'm not sure if in this case they are called terms rather than categories; correct me if I'm wrong!) such as IT, Construction, etc. For arguments sake, let's say under the category IT there is a single post named Web Developer.

First question: With the logic above, how would I manage to reach the single post (web developer) with the URL: *.../video/IT/web developer*?

Second question: If on the video page I would like to display all posts in all categories, what template page should I create? Is it *archive-video.php*? The same question goes for the category (IT in this case): Which template page should I create in order to display all posts under a specific category?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer your second question first:

Yes, the template you should use for displaying all the custom post types would be the CPT archive, so *archive-video.php* sounds right.

For the categories (the exact way to say it would be "taxonomy terms" indeed), you would use *taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php* or even *taxonomy-{taxonomy}-{term}.php* if you need to get more specific.

About your first question, there is currently no core functionality to use custom taxonomies in your permalinks, but [this](http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/add-custom-taxonomy-tags-to-your-wordpress-permalinks) might help you.